# How to add parameters to the SOAP Request

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, saprfc

I want to call RFC function in SAP, I already could make request from Java and get the WSDL response. But I want to send a parameter with the SOAP request? How to do that?

The class below, I used it to create the request and get response :

```
public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "http://10.130.105.8:8000/sap/bc/.....client=520";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        // print SOAP Response
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        soapConnection.close();
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

            // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("pernr","example");
 
        soapBodyElem.addTextNode("10001001");

        String authorization = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(("hr_develop:unrwa2013").getBytes()));

        soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Authorization","Basic " + authorization);
            soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
            return soapMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what you want to send with your request. You are already sending a SOAP body with the content `<pernr> 10001001</pernr>`.

Comment: @Smutje Yes, this a try, I am not sure it will be received correctly or not. What I want to know is how to send the parameter, How to now the tag name and namespace .. The function in SAP has input parameter called pernr. Is the way I am using correct ?